# Haskell packages - dependency tree

Tags: haskell, cabal

In java - `maven` build tool, you can print a tree of dependencies for any `package/project` using the command,

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=commons-collections
```

and output will be a tree structure of `artifacts/dependencies` like,

```
[INFO] [dependency:tree]
[INFO] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:maven-plugin:2.0-alpha-5-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:jar:2.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |        \- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.0)
[INFO] \- org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-site-renderer:jar:1.0-alpha-8:compile
[INFO]    \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-velocity:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO]       \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.0:compile
```

So, how can i do this same for a haskell package using `cabal`?

Comment: I don't think there is an existing way to do this in cabal, although I think there has been some discussion about it here:https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/879. There is a package on hackage that can do this for you though: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-db

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A graph containing all installed packages can be produced using `ghc-pkg`, e.g.

```
ghc-pkg dot | tred | dot -Tpdf >pkgs.pdf
```

Note that the `graphviz` package provides `tred` and the `dot` program.

Comment: btw, why is ghc-pkg given another command `tred` as an argument?

Comment: The data from `ghc-pkg` is fed through the `tred` filter to remove edges between nodes that are transitively connected. The `|` are the pipes of the command line interpreter.

Comment: This should be the marked answer. It is by far the most useful.

Comment: Sometimes `ghc-pkg dot` is very useful by itself. Particularly when generating a pdf leads to something like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/uhj3skc6r3eseby/Screenshot%202017-03-12%2012.26.23.png?dl=0

Comment: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:A_graph_containing_all_installed_Haskell_packages.svg

Comment: How to do this with stack? I installed graphviz by entering "stack install graphviz". Then I tried "stack exec ghc-pkg | stack exec dot | stack exec tred | stack exec dot -- -Tpdf >pkgs.pdf", and it shows errors like: "Executable named dot not found on path", beside others.

Answer (score 1):

For the installed package you can find the dependencies using `ghc-pkg`. For a package named `text`, you have to do:

```
$ ghc-pkg field text depends
depends: array-0.5.0.0-470385a50d2b78598af85cfe9d988e1b
         base-4.7.0.2-bfd89587617e381ae01b8dd7b6c7f1c1
         bytestring-0.10.4.0-d6f1d17d717e8652498cab8269a0acd5
         deepseq-1.3.0.2-63a1ab91b7017a28bb5d04cb1b5d2d02
         ghc-prim-0.3.1.0-a24f9c14c632d75b683d0f93283aea37
         integer-gmp-0.5.1.0-26579559b3647acf4f01d5edd9491a46
```

For any working project all you have to do is see the `depends` field on cabal file to determine it's dependency.

Comment: While this shows the immediate dependencies, the maven feature shows the full dependency tree, which is an important distinction.  It's also a very useful thing to see, particularly given Cabal's tendency to have problems related to transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

To visualize the dependencies of a Stack project:
https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/dependency_visualization/
By default Stack visualizes the internal dependencies.

To visualize the external and internal dependencies of a Cabal project, `cabal-plan` works:
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-plan

i.e.

```
cabal-plan dot | twopi -Groot=ROOT-PACKAGE -Goverlap=false -Tpng -o graph.png
```

(source https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/dependency_visualization/)

To visualize only the internal dependencies of a Cabal project:

```
cabal-plan --hide-global --hide-builtin dot | twopi -Groot=ROOT-PACKAGE -Goverlap=false -Tpng -o graph.png
```

(source https://github.com/haskell-hvr/cabal-plan/issues/84#issuecomment-1073232622)